# Backup all working copy files to another directory

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is that possible to have a feature to backup all working copy files to another directory instead of manually copy one-by-one myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can...you can set-up a [cron job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an [export](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html)?